# Django Social Auth Update First And Last Name in Django App Permanently

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am using django-social-auth to simplify the coded needed to use Auth0 to authenticate for the django application. I want to give my users the functionality to update their first and last names within the django application and have set up an edit profile form to do so. However, after changing their first and last name, once a user logs out and logs back in, their name is re-written so that their first name is their email and they have no last name. I have already tested to make sure the form is working properly (both from the app front end and the database). Is there something I need to configure to prevent social-auth from re-setting the user's name each time they log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured this issue out. All I needed to do was properly set up SOCIAL_AUTH_PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS as such:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```